# Can we convert graph to matrix or an array in matlab?

Tags: matlab, graph, matrix

I have plotted a graph with the values from  text file and given data. Is there any function to convert that graph or extract data from the graph's x and y axis end values.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a handle `h` to your plot you can recover the original data:

```
h = plot(x,y);
x_recovered = get(h,'XData');
y_recovered = get(h,'YData');
```

If you didn't get a handle you can click right on the plot and then write the command

```
h = gco;
```

to obtain the handle `h` (this replaces first line above)